# Issue with using 'map' in RxJava 2 / RxAndroid 2

Tags: java, android, rx-java, reactive-programming, rx-android

I'm trying to learn RXJAVA for Android. Parts make sense and I'm still confused about a lot of the other bits but, given some time I hope it will all make a lot more sense.

At present I'm having trouble with the 'map' functionality. I'm receiving an error but cannot quite figure out how to resolve it.

Before I share my code, I'll explain my understanding..
At a simple level..
Observable - Code that emits data.
Observer - Code that processes the emitted data.
Map - Code that takes in data of type A and returns it processed or as type B.

So, with this in mind:

In gradle I have:

```
compile 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxjava:2.0.1' 
compile 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxandroid:2.0.1'
```

If I have:

```
    //declaration at top of file
    private Observable<Integer> myIntObservable;
    private Observer<Integer> myIntObserver;
    private Observer<String> myStringObserver;
    private Observable<String> myStringObservable;

    //usage in a function
    myIntObserver = new Observer<Integer>() {
        @Override
        public void onSubscribe(Disposable d) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onNext(Integer value) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "" + value, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(Throwable e) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onComplete() {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Int Observer Async Complete", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    };


    //Connect my Observable to the observer.
    myIntObservable.observeOn(Schedulers.io());
    myIntObservable.subscribeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread());
    myIntObservable.subscribe(myIntObserver);
```

This all works fine... my map usage is similar..

What I would like to do is use this same observable that returns an int, then use the map code to instead return a string...

Therefore:

```
    myStringObservable
            .observeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .subscribeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .map(new Function<Integer, String>() {
                @Override
                public String apply(Integer query){
                    return "String Observable result == " + query;
                }
            });
```

Now, I have two issues:

a) The build error I receive is:
*Error:(179, 17) error: method map in class Observable cannot be applied to given types;
required: Function
found: >
reason: cannot infer type-variable(s) R
(argument mismatch; > cannot be converted to Function)
where R,T are type-variables:
R extends Object declared in method map(Function)
T extends Object declared in class Observable*

I believe that this is essentially telling me that the types are not correct for my usage but, I can't clearly see... how to resolve this.

b) The map code that I have posted above doesn't connect the observable to what it needs to observe... hence, should I add the subscribe line before the map command?

Therefore, I tried this..

```
public void setupAsyncSubscription(){

    myIntObservable
            .observeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .subscribeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe(myIntObserver)
            .map(new Function<Integer, String>() {
                @Override
                public String apply(Integer query){
                    return "String Observable result == " + query;
                }
            });

}
```

Whilst this removes the error detailed in 'a' it instead provides me with the following error:

Error:(180, 17) error: void cannot be dereferenced (this points to the 'map' call)

Finally, I can also see that what I 'return' back from the 'map' function isn't being processed at all... I'm not clear how to process that. I feel that I should be using the .subscribe call in that case??

I 'think' that I am slowly on the right path to resolving the issue(s), but I'm not quite there and I don't want to just try and happen upon the answer without understanding what the problem is.

As always, any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have multiple issues here. There are - one by one:

```
//Connect my Observable to the observer.
myIntObservable.observeOn(Schedulers.io());
myIntObservable.subscribeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread());
myIntObservable.subscribe(myIntObserver);
```

Code above would not work as you probably think.

Operators `observeOn`, `subscribeOn` are not designed to change internal observable state. They are returning new observable with desired behaviour.

To accomplish observing on `io()` thread and subscribing your observable on `mainThread()` you need to change the code:

```
//Connect my Observable to the observer.
myIntObservable = myIntObservable.observeOn(Schedulers.io());
myIntObservable = myIntObservable.subscribeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread());
myIntObservable.subscribe(myIntObserver);
```

Or use (preferred) chaining:

```
//Connect my Observable to the observer.
myIntObservable
    .observeOn(Schedulers.io());
    .subscribeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread());
    .subscribe(myIntObserver);
```

For the code same as yours, calling `.subscribe()` on not changed `Observable` will result in subscribing and observing on the same thread from which you call `.subscribe()` (most likely from main thread).

Keep in mind you need to dispose observable once the work is finished.

When it comes to mapping problem - `map()` operator changes one type of `Observable<A>` into another type of observable `Observable<B>`.

If you'd like to end up with `String` objects converted from `Integer` objects you need to use - as a source of data - your original `myIntObservable`:

```
myStringObservable = myIntObservable
    (...)    
    .map(new Function<Integer, String>() {
        @Override
        public String apply(Integer query){
            return "String Observable result == " + query;
        }
    });
```

In above example `myIntObservable` will emit `Integer` objects (as expected in `.apply(Integer query)` method. Then `.map()` operator will create another `Observable` of type `Observable<String>` you can assign to `myStringObservable` (or do whatever you want from here).

Then, using `myStringObservable` you can subscribe to its events:

```
myStringObservable.subscribe(myStringObserver)
```

Again, please remember to dispose `Observable` when work is done.

Please also note that you should:

- `.observeOn()` as soon as possible for current piece of work,
- `.subscribeOn()` as late as possible (you don't want to continue `io()` or `computation()` operations on your main thread, right?).

Hint at the end: consider using lambdas with RxJava. Using all these anonymous classes (`new Function()` etc.) will make your code hard to read in the nearest future.

Comment: Hi. Thank you for taking the time to respond and for the detailed response.

I have modified my code based on your answer and it now behaves as I want it to. Thank you for that.

I have one final query...you mentioned that I should dispose of the Observable once I've finished with it.. I understand why, but I'm confused about how. I can't see any methods such as .dispose which I can call after 'onComplete'... I was expecting to be able to do something such as myStringObservable.dispose(), and I can't assign myStringObservable to a Disposable either...

Comment: Use `DisposableObserver`. Or better - rather than using observers, use `Consumer`s (all .subscribe() method for consumers returns `Disposable`s). Then you can achieve from using `CompositeDisposable` for disposing multiple observables with ease.

Answer (score 1):

The first problem is that `myStringObservable` emits object of class `String`, but you're trying to map function which expects arguments of class `Integer`. In order to achieve what you want you should use `myIntObservable`.

The second problem is that `subscribe` call returns a `Disposable` object for you and you can't do `map` after that. Remove that `subscribe` call and this should be fine. Please also note that your method signature tells that it returns `String` but it can't return String, it can return `Observable<String>`.

Comment: Hi. Thank you for taking the time to respond and for the explanations you have provided.